# How to reduce the refresh rate of the Raspberry Pi HDMI port

Tags: pi-3, hdmi

I have an older TV, and it turns on and off after a few minutes of use with my Raspberry Pi.

As I suspect this is because the TV is either no longer capable of, or was never capable of the refresh rate being provided to it, I was hoping someone could help me determine how to configure this for a conventional, low end display device; I suspect it is the /boot/config.txt file, but it may also be raspi-config

All help is welcome and appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I am sceptical that refresh is your problem, however https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=5851 shows possible values.

`tvservice -s` will show you what the current setting on your Pi is.

`tvservice` will show you the commands which can be used, including to list what your TV supports.